# How can I make ShinyApp to use environmental variables when deployed on the web?

Tags: r, shiny

For hours I've been struggling. My `Shiny App` is supposed to display some variables that I have in my R environment. It works all works fine but when I deploy it to the web I get errors like:

```
Error: object 'df1' not found
```

How can I add `df1` and my other data frames so they can be packaged as part of the `Shiny App` when it is deployed?

Please help. Here's my sample code:

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input,output){
output$datasets <- renderTable({
switch(input$choice,

         "1" = as.data.frame(df1)          
         "2" = as.data.frame(df2) })
  }))
```

`UI.R`

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",

sidebarPanel(        
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.theTab == 'datasets' ",
    h3('Display Sample Data'),    
    selectInput("choice", "Selection", choices = c("Group1"=1,"Group2"=2)),

  )),

mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel( "datasets", tableOutput("datasets"), value = 'datasets'),
    id = "theTab"))
)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @jdharrison thanks john i've added a shorter version of my code

Comment: @jdharrison basically i have `df1` and `df2` in my R environment and I just want to display them. It works when I run the app locally but when I deploy it `R` says it cannot find the objects `df1` and `df2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution!! basically I was supposed to load my workspace at the top of the `UI.R` file. This way:

```
attach("myWorkspace.RData")
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend not relying on this. Instead make the creation of df1 and df2 an explicit part of your code.

Comment: @hadley any recommendation when df1 and df2 (or R6 obj) are desired to be created interactively in R console. Having them user would start shiny app from console. `global.R` not covers that.

Comment: @jangorecki Write a function that takes df1 and df2 as arguments, then create the app and run it.

Comment: @hadley IMO your comment looks to be the best answer to asked question

Answer (score 4):

In recent shiny versions you can include variables in a *global.R* file, and those will be available for ui and server. Take a look at the scoping rules here:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: thanks I tried that but I cant generate the data on the fly because it relies on local files

Comment: mm, yes, but still, you are reading files and then maybe processing or computing. If you do that in global.R then it will be visible to ui.R and server.R. Maybe I am missing how do you obtain df1 and df2 in your example.