# R Shiny Error object not found in server.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that runs fine locally. However, when I deploy it on shinyapps.io I encounter the following error:

> Error: object 'actuarialtable' not found.

where actuarialtable is an rds object I am trying to load in my server.R file. I have files "ui.r", "server.R", and "helpers.R" in my app folder with a "data" subfolder containing files "actuarialtable.rds" and "SMData.rds"

My server.R file is as follows:

```
source("helpers.R")
actuarialtable <- readRDS("data/actuarialtable.rds")
SMData <- readRDS("data/SMData.rds")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    RunSim(
      currentAge = input$currentAge,
      retireAge = input$retireAge,
      numsamples = input$numsamples,
      initValue = input$initValue,
      stockpct = input$stockpct / 100,
      moncont = input$moncont,
      maxWd = input$wdRange[2],
      minWd = input$wdRange[1],
      sex = input$sex,
      partnerAge = input$partnerAge,
      partnerSex = input$partnerSex
    )
  })

<Some other code plotting output of RunSim()> 

})
```

It seems that for some reason, my "actuarialtable.rds" file is not being loaded, but I have no idea why. My working directory is the directory containing my app. Using Windows, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried deleting everything from the environment and then running the app locally?

Comment: This probably has to do with environments. For example, the line at the top that sources won't work in shiny unless `local=TRUE` is specified

Comment: Thank you both Mhairi and Carl for your comments. My app would not run locally after removing everything from the environment. After specifying local=TRUE, everything seems to be working. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try the 3rd solution at this link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654835/how-can-i-make-shinyapp-to-use-environmental-variables-when-deployed-on-the-web)